# During the Battle over Genesis in ST3: Search for Spock, what were the screens displaying when Chekov tried to raise the shields?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, the-search-for-spock

During the battle scene in the middle of Star Trek 3: The Search for Spock, after Scotty successfully fires two photon torpedoes into Kruge's bird of prey, Admiral Kirk orders Chekov to raise shields as a precautionary measure.

After Kruge reroutes emergency power to thrusters to right his ship post-attack, Chekov mentions the shields are non-responsive. Where he sits at the Science Station, and on one of the screens of the station directly behind the Captain's chair, it shows a diagram of the Enterprise and the dots that indicate the shield, blinking and malfunctioning.

In text right below this diagram on the screen, 3 or 4 words are scrolling by about once a second.

I cant take screenshots to provide context, but I can see at first

"Emergency Emergency Emergency"
then
"*something something* Transfer"
then
"*something* Circuits Analyzed"

Anyone know what these screens were supposed to say or have clearer screenshots? The camera focus is on Chekov's face rather than the screen so this might be impossible